# SQL запрос для вывода двух последних пользователей каждой группы

Tags: sql, postgresql

В проекте использующим PostgreSQL имеется таблица users, со следующей структурой:[image: Фото таблицы]

Необходимо написать SQL запрос, который выведет по 2 последних зарегистрировавшихся юзера из каждой группы

Comment: вы пробовали написать запрос самостоятельно?

Comment: Да, но пока не выходит нужный результат(

Comment: покажите запрос, который Вы написали

Comment: То же самое ^^^, только order by по убыванию даты и rn<=2 конечно

Comment: select *
  from (
    select A.*, row_number() over(partition by result order by null) RN
      from work A
  )
 where RN<=2